# Factorial Huge Number Python

Tags: python, factorial

I am trying to make a program that can compute the factorial of 987654321, but I can't find a way to do it.

```
def range_prod(lo,hi):
    if lo+1 < hi:
        mid = (hi+lo)//2
        return range_prod(lo,mid) * range_prod(mid+1,hi)
    if lo == hi:
        return lo
    return lo*hi

def treefactorial(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return range_prod(1,n)
print(treefactorial(987654321))
```

Comment: That number is astronomically large.  Shoot for `factorial(54321)` instead.

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)

Answer (score 4):

The proposed approaches will take a very long time to compute.  If you're OK with losing some precision, you can get an approximate value quickly using the LogGamma function, for example

```
math.exp(scipy.special.gammaln(3+1))
=> 6.0

scipy.special.gammaln(987654322)
=> 19467499583.824226
```

so `987654321!` is approximately `exp(19467499583.824226)` you can convert to `log 10` base to find the number of digits...

ps. It will have more than 8 billion digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin `math.factorial`

```
import math
math.factorial(n)
```

Or you can use `reduce` function to calculate factorial

```
from operator import mul
```

> for Python 2.7

```
factorial = lambda n: reduce(mul, xrange(1, n+1))
```

> for Python 3

```
factorial = lambda n: reduce(mul, range(1, n+1))

>>> factorial(987654321)
```

Comment: Good luck with that.  `factorial(54321)` has 233,620 digits and takes a second or so to compute.  `factorial(654321)` hasn't returned after a couple minutes.

Comment: @MarkTolonen You are right but I could not find a faster way to find factorial of a large number. However, in some cases, you really don't need to calculate this value even if factorial is involed. e.g. in combication formula, there are three factorial involved `nCr = n! / ((n-r)! * r!)` so if you want to calculate combications of 2 with 1000 items, you just need 2 multiplications and not all three factorials ans then division and multiplication.

Comment: But that is not the question.

Comment: @MarkTolonen You are righ. Question is about factorial of a large number but it was not mentioned that there are time constraints. IMO, we can't find exact factorial value faster than this, however, we can find approximate values